# How can I modify a web page using google chrome content script before the DOM is processed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Using chrome content scripts I want to remove several iframes in a webpage before their content is loaded.

I found, that using the property run_at:document_start in the extentions manifest my javascript is executed just after the main page request and before the DOM is processed and images, iframes etc. are loaded. Logicaly at this point the DOM structure is not availabel and I can not modify the page using commands like:

```
myelement=document.getElementById('iframeX');

myelement.parentNode.removeChild(myelement);
```

How can i access and modify the reqeusted page data then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to trigger your content script on document_start and add a beforeload listener - you can use event.preventDefault to selectively block content from loading and then remove the frame that tried to load the content:

```
    document.addEventListener('beforeload', function(event) {
        if (event.url.match('facebook')) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(event.target).remove();
        }
    }, false);
```

I've [blogged about an equivalent approach to using the beforeload event for Firefox](http://blog.webmynd.com/2011/04/04/equivalent-to-beforeload-event-for-firefox-extensions/) also.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I had to modify the code a bit to work (might be chrome specific):

`document.addEventListener('beforeload', function(event) {

       if (event.url.match(/facebook.com/)) {

            event.preventDefault();

            $(event.target).remove();

        }
  
    }, true);
`

Btw: Where did you know i meant facebook :)

Comment: Ha, blind luck! I guess Facebook is in the category of ajaxy apps that lots of people want to modify :-)

Comment: Note that `event.preventDefault()` doesn't prevent the content from being retrieved by Chrome (I don't think there is any way of doing that just yet). It still gets downloaded, just not executed (if it's a script).

Answer (score 2):

The manifest.json for this should contain `content_scripts` like:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {   
        "matches": ["*://*/*"], 
        "js": [ "scan.js" ],
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "all_frames" : true
    }
]
```