# Chrome Extension Inject for ad blocking

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, element

I want to block an iframe that contains an ad in this chrome extension i'm developing. I tried using CSS and Javascript to inject code that would work, but haven't had any luck. I know there are adblockers available, but i want to remove the ad on my side for convenience. Thanks in advance.

Comment: block the ads,but show your code

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304530/how-can-i-modify-a-web-page-using-google-chrome-content-script-before-the-dom-is

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a `beforeload` event handler in your content script. See [documentation of this event](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW9), in short you check `event.url` and call `event.preventDefault()` if you want to block. Please note that there is currently a severe bug associated with this event: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45586. Just have a look at the number of bug reports this causes for the Adblock extension: http://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/issues/detail?id=3701 (Adblock Plus also got tons of bug reports, these aren't as centralized however).