# Browser extension content script to manipulate DOM as soon as a specific element loads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am working on a browser extension (MV2, Firefox), that manipulates the DOM of a simple HTML page. It is to add new DOM elements if the page has a specific element.

If my content script's run_at is set to "document_end", the DOM is presented to the user first, then my content script runs, then it puts the new elements on the page - my added elements will load later than the original page, so they noticeably "blink" when being loaded.

**My goal is to prevent this "blink", so my elements would blend seamlessly in the page.**

The page is practically a HTML-based single page application - when you interact with the app, the page reloads, the UI elements are cached and stay in the same place, so they practically never disappear from the screen, but my injected elements will, for a fraction of a second. The caveat is, that the app has pages with a different layout as well, where I don't need to inject the same elements, thus I need a detection logic to run before I inject.

Example:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "demo extension",
    "version": "1",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm" ],
            "js" : ["main.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

**main.js:**

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.style.position = "absolute";
image.style.top = 300;
image.style.left = 400;
image.src = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/thinking-face.png";

// dummy logic to determine whether the image should be injected
if( document.getElementsByClassName("img_whs1")[0] !== undefined ){
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(image)
}
```

If you load this then navigate to http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm, the injected image will load after the DOM, so you can see the image "blink". If you refresh the page, the image blinks again.

---

My understanding is that I will need to have my content script to run_at: "document_start" for sure, so my content script can intercept the loading of the particular DOM element that it will use to determine what to do next.

I saw [an old StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304530/how-can-i-modify-a-web-page-using-google-chrome-content-script-before-the-dom-is) mentioning a beforeLoad event listener, but I cannot find any documentation on this event and I cannot make it work, I guess it has been deprecated.

Using mutation observers gave me a hard time - when the script is loaded at document_start, the only DOM element I have is the HTML tag. When I debug the following simple snippet, I see that the body tag will load all it's contents at once, so once I get there, it's too late.

**main2.js**

```
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
    debugger
}
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

observer.observe(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0], config)
```

What approach should I follow here? Is there a way to make the mutation observer to listen for changes in the body tag before the body tag has been loaded? Once again, the flow I want to achieve is:

1. My content script loads at document_start
2. As soon as a specific HTML element is loaded, my script determines from that element if it needs to inject something
3. Inject the new elements if necessary (or at least a placeholder, to prevent blinking, then do the rest of the logic later)

Answer (score 0):

Hide all elements with CSS when the DOM is injected with HEAD and unhide it at your own time.
This is a snippet of an extension I made earlier.

matches.js

```js
const setVisibilityHidden = () => {
  const style = document.createElement("style");
  style.id = "visibility_hidden";
  style.innerHTML = "* {visibility: hidden}";
  document.head.insertBefore(style, null);
};

const resetVisibilityHidden = () => {
  document.getElementById("visibility_hidden").remove();
};

const onMutation = (mutations) => {
  for (const mutation of mutations) {
    for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
      if (node.nodeName == "HEAD") {
        mo.disconnect();
        setVisibilityHidden();
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}

const observe = () => {
  mo.observe(document, {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true,
  });
}

const mo = new MutationObserver(onMutation);

observe();
```

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "matches.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand what your code does, and I realize that you are running the mutation observer on the document instead of the HTML tag - that is what I need to do to detect the necessary element. I will do some tests and then get back to you.

Comment: Please disregard my earlier comment, the mutation observer on the document tag still did the same thing - it only triggers for my IMG when the whole body is loaded. 

Calling the resetVisibilityHidden() function at document_end would result in the whole page blinking during reload. How would you suggest calling the resetVisibilityHidden() function when the getElementsByClassName("img_whs1") becomes available?

Comment: Shouldn't `resetVisibilityHidden` be called when `img_whs1` is detected in `onMutation`?

Comment: I withdraw my previous comment. It's easier to call it after `appendChild` in `main.js`.

Comment: Seems like my problem was with how Firefox visualizes the DOM when I put a breakpoint in a mutation observer. If I do `if (node.nodeName == "IMG" && node.src == "http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/htmlpage.jpg") {debugger;} `, when I hit the breakpoint, the whole DOM is loaded on the screen, so that is why I guessed it is too late for me to run my code there. I need to do further testing, this might just work.